# ListView Item is retaining state of deleted Item

Tags: android, listview

I have some complex list view item. Some list item have different font and images and background. After some processing I am deleting that custom item. But list item just after that is taking up the attributes of deleted item. I know this is because in list view only filled value is changed not the layout. But can anybody suggest me a simple way of preventing this. I have a working code here.

```
    if(condition == true)
    {
        listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        listItem.setAlpha(0.24f);
        viewHolder.setIcon();
    }
    else
    {
        listItem.setAlpha(1f);
        viewHolder.resetIcon();
    }
```

Is there any other better way of doing this then putting this if - else block.

Comment: this is good way to do it.. but also you can do is that you can inflate layout for all the child items. but that can lead to decreased performance.

Comment: How do you decide when to use a custom item and when to not use it?  Is it based on the item's position in the list?

Comment: @Jonathan No its not based on position, Its based on some value returned from server side and cross checking it.

Comment: Assuming that this code is in the getView() Adapter for your ListView I don't see much of a problem with it tbh.  The general pattern I follow for my Adapters' getView() method is inflate a general list item layout, and then fill it in according to the data in that specific item.

Comment: Have you tried YourClass.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); after deleting your custom view.